# IndexOutOfBoundException when i pass arraylist to DBHelper to update database (Android SQlite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, android-sqlite

I am new at android and trying to make managing members app with database. what i want to do here is that when user buys any drink it should change drinks name to "bought" in database, but when i pass Arraylist to db class it shows that my Arraylist is empty.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.shashank.managemembers.DB_Controller.update_available(DB_Controller.java:88)
        at com.shashank.managemembers.TempActivity$2.onClick(TempActivity.java:90)
```

**userInputActivity**

here user selects drink he/she wants and when he presses done button it should change database with drinks name.
And I'm checking it with Toast message that ArrayList is not empty. Toast message always appears with user's choice but db class throws error.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(TempActivity.this, selectedInListView.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dbController.update_available(code, selectedInListView);
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```

here selectedInListView has many items when i am passing it to dbController.update_available.

**dbController.java**

here I have 9 columns in db starting from DRINK1 to DRINK9.

```
public void update_available(String memberCode, ArrayList<String> BoughtDrinks) {
    Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MEMBERS WHERE MEMBERCODE = '" + memberCode + "'", null);
    int count = cursor.getColumnCount();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        for (int i = 5; i < count; i++) {
            if (!cursor.getString(i).contains(BoughtDrinks.get(0))) {
                this.getReadableDatabase().execSQL("UPDATE MEMBERS SET DRINK"+ i +"='Bought' WHERE DRINK" + i +"='" + BoughtDrinks.get(0) + "'" + "AND MEMBERCODE='" + memberCode + "'");
                if(BoughtDrinks.size() > 0 ){
                    BoughtDrinks.remove(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

I am not understanding why it is throwing an error when I'm passing ArrayList with elements.

Comment: Apparently, `BoughtDrinks` has a `size()` of `0`, hence `BoughtDrinks.get(0)` throws said exception. --- Two remarks on your code: - variable names should start with a lowercase letter (`BoughtDrinks` -> `boughtDrinksv`) - method names should be written in `camelCase`, not `snake_case` (`update_available` -> `updateAvailable`)

Comment: Maybe initially the list is not empty, but in the loop there is: `BoughtDrinks.remove(0);` so in the next iteration the list may be empty.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for advice but can you tell me more why boughtDrinks.size() has size of 0 it shouldn't be more than zero?? because i am passing arraylist with elements, and i am removing elements from arraylist but i put condition there if there is only one element left it will not remove last element.

Comment: Please look at [forpas's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67850221/indexoutofboundexception-when-i-pass-arraylist-to-dbhelper-to-update-database-a?noredirect=1#comment119927174_67850221) --- Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this error because ,if BoughtDrinks.size()>0 ,your code remove item at 0 then for loop get item at 0.So when you try to get item at 0 after  you removed all the item ,you will get index IndexOutOfBoundsException.to avoid that just add if() condition.

```
 public void update_available(String memberCode, ArrayList<String> BoughtDrinks) {
        Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MEMBERS WHERE MEMBERCODE = '" + memberCode + "'", null);
        int count = cursor.getColumnCount();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            for (int i = 5; i < count; i++) {
                if ( BoughtDrinks.size()>0 && !cursor.getString(i).contains(BoughtDrinks.get(0))) {
                    this.getReadableDatabase().execSQL("UPDATE MEMBERS SET DRINK"+ i +"='Bought' WHERE DRINK" + i +"='" + BoughtDrinks.get(0) + "'" + "AND MEMBERCODE='" + memberCode + "'");
                    if(BoughtDrinks.size() > 0 ){
                        BoughtDrinks.remove(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```